# How to add Done button to the keyboard?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, programmatically-created

UPDATE:

I also tried implementing UITextViewDelegate delegate and then doing in my controller:

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

I also set the delegate of the text view to be self (controller view instance).

Clicking the Done button still inserts just a new line :(

---

UPDATE:

What I have done so far. I have implemented a UITextFieldDelegate by my view controller.

I have connected the text view to the view controller via outlet.

Then I did:

---

```
self.myTextView.delegate = self;
```

And:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

But when I click on Done button, it just adds a new line.

So I have a UITextView element on my scene and when a user taps it, keyboard appears and it can be edited.

However, I cannot dismiss the keyboard.

How can I add Done button to the keyboard so it can be dismissed?

Comment: @joerick I tried your link. When I click on the Done button, it just inserts a new line.

Comment: Show us what you've got so far; post the code you're using at the moment, and then we can see what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: @joerick Check my latest update (on top of my post). I have tried everything, your link (and others as well) and all answers posted on this page. Clicking Done still just adds a new line :(

Answer (score 128, accepted):

thats quite simple :)

```
[textField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
```

for dismissing the keyboard implement the `<UITextFieldDelegate>` protocol in your class, set

```
textfield.delegate = self;
```

and use

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

or

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I did all that and clicking the Done button still just inserts a new line. Check my updated question.

Comment: hi,
you should be able to figure out what went wrong. i posted you code for a UITextField, and you copied it for your UITextView without changing it. use a `UITextField`, implement `<UITextFieldDelegate>` and use the code i provided you with :)
a UITextView cant use the UITextFieldDelegate of course. 
however you can use the `<UITextViewDelegate>` protocol if you really want to stick to the textview. more info: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html

Comment: Thanks. I have used UITextVieDelegate and it works. One question. Is it possible to allow multiple lines and also have a done button to dismiss the keyboard? I mean, is it possible to have both return and done buttons?

Comment: have never tried it, but you could set an integer in your class, and every time someone enters a `\n` character increment the counter, and when you hit the maximum of lines you resign firstresponder

Comment: textFieldShouldReturn must be implemented, not `or`, it is an `and`

Comment: @ideawu `optional func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool`. it is optional. if not needed, dont implement it.

Comment: @SebastianFlückiger if you don't implemtn textFieldShouldReturn and return YES, textFieldDidEndEditing will not get called. I am pretty sure.

Comment: it's an optional function as per definition :)

Comment: In swift this doesnt work self.textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done;

Comment: For me it's working with the only textFieldShouldReturn, no need for textFieldDidEndEditing. Writing in Swift 4.1

Answer (score 19):

**Add UIToolBar as custom view that will have Done button as UIBarButtonItem in it.**

*This is safer and cleaner way to add Done button to any Type of Keyboard. Create UIToolBar add Done Button to it and set inputAccessoryView of any UITextField or UITextView.*

```
UIToolbar *ViewForDoneButtonOnKeyboard = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
[ViewForDoneButtonOnKeyboard sizeToFit];
UIBarButtonItem *btnDoneOnKeyboard = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self
                                                              action:@selector(doneBtnFromKeyboardClicked:)];
[ViewForDoneButtonOnKeyboard setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:btnDoneOnKeyboard, nil]];

myTextField.inputAccessoryView = ViewForDoneButtonOnKeyboard;
```

**IBAction For Done Button**

```
 - (IBAction)doneBtnFromKeyboardClicked:(id)sender
  {
      NSLog(@"Done Button Clicked.");

      //Hide Keyboard by endEditing or Anything you want.
      [self.view endEditing:YES];
  }
```

**SWIFT 3**

```
var ViewForDoneButtonOnKeyboard = UIToolbar()
ViewForDoneButtonOnKeyboard.sizeToFit()
var btnDoneOnKeyboard = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .bordered, target: self, action: #selector(self.doneBtnFromKeyboardClicked))
ViewForDoneButtonOnKeyboard.items = [btnDoneOnKeyboard]
myTextField.inputAccessoryView = ViewForDoneButtonOnKeyboard
```

*Function*

```
  @IBAction func doneBtnFromKeyboardClicked (sender: Any) {
     print("Done Button Clicked.")
    //Hide Keyboard by endEditing or Anything you want.
    self.view.endEditing(true)
  }
```

Comment: On Xcode 11.2, building for iOS 12, I get an autolayout crash unless I used `let ViewForDoneButtonOnKeyboard = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 500.0, height: 70))`. The `CGRect` is completely arbitrary but Xcode dumped out a line: `<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x283c6ff70 h=--& v=--& _UIToolbarContentView:0x102c5e7f0.width == 0   (active)>`, so providing a width seemed to fix this

Answer (score 18):

Go into your storyboard, select your text field and under the Attributes Inspector there is an option that says "return key"...select "Done".

Then go into your ViewController and add:

```
- (IBAction)dismissKeyboard:(id)sender;
{
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Then go back to your text field, click outlets and link "Did end on exit" to dismissKeyboard action.

Comment: thank you mike your answer helped me in my app. i gave you an up vote and thank you. adrian

Answer (score 12):

Swift version:

In Your ViewController:

```
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
textField.delegate = self
```

After your ViewController

```
extension MyViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {        
    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Swift 4 told me to update to ` func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {`

Answer (score 1):

Set the `'Return Key'` option under the `text field` option in the inspector for your text field.
    Then right click on the text field and while holding `CTRL` select `'Did End On Exit'` and drag this into your `view controllers` file. This will create an `IBAction` method. Give the method a name and then enter the following values:

```
[textField becomeFirstResponder];
[textField resignFirstResponder];
```

Your method should look like this:

```
- (IBAction)methodName:(id)sender;
{
    [sender becomeFirstResponder];
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I too have been struggling with this very issue. Currently I am accessing a UITextView in a UITableViewCell (via Tags). Because I am using prototype cells I cannot use IBActions nor IBOutlets like everyone suggests. Instead, I am using;

> -(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text

This will then provide me with the text each time the user hits a button. My solution then, was to get the ascii character for new line; "/n". If that is the text that was entered, I would resign the first responder. For example;

> ```
> // If the text length is 0 then the user is deleting something, so only check the ascii character if there is text to check
> if (text.length != 0) {
>     // Get the Ascii character
>     int asciiCode = [text characterAtIndex:0];
>     // If the ascii code is /n or new line, then resign first responder
>     if (asciiCode == 10) {
>         [alertTextView resignFirstResponder];
>         [DeviceTextView resignFirstResponder];
>     }
> }
> ```

Not sure if anyone else will need this hacky solution but I figured I'd put it out there in case someone needs it!

Answer (score 1):

This is best way to add Done Button on keyboard

```
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is my approach, in `Swift 3`. When the `doneBtn` clicked, let it send `.editingDidEndOnExit` event. I use this event to handle focus problem between multiple textFields.

```
// My customized UITextField
class MyTextField: UITextField {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        // Add toolBar when keyboardType in this set. 
        let set : [UIKeyboardType] = [.numberPad, .phonePad]
        if (set.contains(self.keyboardType) ) {
            self.addDoneToolbar()
        }
    }

    // Add a toolbar with a `Done` button
    func addDoneToolbar() {

        let toolbar = UIToolbar()
        let space = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)
        let doneBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(onToolBarDone))

        toolbar.items = [space, doneBtn]
        toolbar.sizeToFit()

        self.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    }

    @objc func onToolBarDone() {
        // I use `editingDidEndOnExit` to simulate the `Done` behavior 
        // on the original keyboard.
        self.sendActions(for: .editingDidEndOnExit)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift 5 and above versions**

```
    extension UITextField {

   func addDoneButtonOnKeyboard() {
       let keyboardToolbar = UIToolbar()
       keyboardToolbar.sizeToFit()
       let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace,
           target: nil, action: nil)
       let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done,
           target: self, action: #selector(resignFirstResponder))
       keyboardToolbar.items = [flexibleSpace, doneButton]
       self.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolbar
   }
}
extension UITextView{
    func addDoneButtonKeyboard(){
        let keyboardToolbar = UIToolbar()
        keyboardToolbar.sizeToFit()
        let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace,
                                            target: nil, action: nil)
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done,
                                         target: self, action: #selector(resignFirstResponder))
        keyboardToolbar.items = [flexibleSpace, doneButton]
        self.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolbar
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**iOS 14+ Solution**

**Edit: Worked for me on iOS 15 but not on iOS 16**

This will place a "done" button in the center of the field above the keybaord.

```
TextField("MyField")
 .toolbar{
    Button("Done"){
    //Close keyboard
    UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }.tint(.blue)
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

In Interface Builder on the properties of the textView you can set the return button type to Done.

Then you need to check for when the Return button is pressed using

```
  - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
```

Check if the text == "/n" then dismiss the keyboard by resigning first responder on your textView.